# Unsubscribed Incredibuild Agent

Tags: incredibuild

The system tray icon for my Incredibuild installation is showing up with a caution icon and noted as Unsubscribed

```
Incredibuild Agent - Unsubscribed
```

What does this mean exactly?

[image: Unsubscribed Incredibuild agent]

Some local IT started to help me get this software setup, but I've never had it running and it fell on the backburner. We updated our Network coordinator and my PC passed the test in connecting to the coordinator computer. What does one have to do to subscribe and what exactly would my PC be subscribing to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need someone with access to the coordinator to subscribe you. It's not something you can fix on the client end.

Read [here](https://www.incredibuild.com/frequently-asked-questions-technical.html#q124).

Once configured the system tray icon on the client end will change to...

```
Incredibuild Agent - Enabled
```

[image: Subscribed Incredibuild Client--"Enabled"]

Comment: Solid, got my guys to subscribe me. Going to edit the answer for a screenshot. Thanks a bunch.